# Как задать параметры ввода при условиях:

Tags: python

Не могу никак сообразить как написать код для каждой строки и связать их между собой

```
name = input('Введите имя: ')
```

Имя не должно включать числа и символы, только буквы

```
birthday = input('Введите дату рождения в формате год-месяц-день: ')
```

Дата рождения должна быть только в формате год-месяц-день

```
mail = input('Введите почту: ')
```

при вводе почты обязательное условие символы `'@'` и `'.'`

Мой код:

```
    name = input('Введите имя: ')
    if name(input([а - яА - Яa - zA - Z])):  # допустимые символы
        print('Имя введено корректно.')
    else name(input([0 - 9])):  # недопустимые символы
        print('Имя введено не корректно, попробуйте еще раз'
```

моя ошибка: Файл "C:\Users\user\untitled-1.py", строка 4, из     else name(input([0 - 9])): # недопустимые символы
Syntax Error: expected ':': , line 4, pos 6

Comment: В чём у вас возникли сложности?

Comment: Не могу сообразить как начать правильно писать код. Начал недавно учиться и получил такое домашнее задание. Перелапатил интернет и только сложнее стало в понимании.
Я пишу 
name = input('Введите имя: ')
if ......и ступор....

Comment: Код добавляйте в свой вопрос. В комментариях нет форматирования, читать код в комментариях сложно.

Comment: @CrazyElf исправил

Comment: Как я понимаю, вам нужны [регулярные выражения](https://habr.com/ru/post/115825/). В питоне для этого используется модуль [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что ``name(input([а - яА - Яa - zA - Z]))`` делает что-то похожее на то, что тебе нужно?

Comment: @Эникейщик как я понял, этот вариант допускает ввод данных символов

Comment: @mironovmeow ознакомлюсь

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тоем случае можно решить проблему через регулярные выражения или с помощью библиотеки validators.
Написал регулярку, возможно где-то опечатался, но вроде все работает как надо:

```
import re

name = birthday = mail = None
name_pattern = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+$')
date_pattern = re.compile(r'^([1-9]\d{3})[.-/\\](?:0[1-9]|1[1-2])[.-/\\]([0-2]\d|3[0-1])$')
email_pattern = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9o-]+)+$')
incorrect_msg = "Некорректный ввод, попробуйте еще раз: "

name = input('Введите имя: ')
while not name_pattern.match(name):
    name = input(incorrect_msg)

birthday = input('Введите дату рождения: ')
while not date_pattern.match(birthday):
    birthday = input(incorrect_msg)

email = input('Введите почту: ')
while not email_pattern.match(email):
    email = input(incorrect_msg)
```